# Excel: What If Analysis: Result is based on changing Vlookup

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a summary table to find the best yielding pair of 25 unique pairings (5 level 1 heros and 5 unique level 2 heros) (The answer from Column R 31-R35)

File Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14HQagU-hCuSetenj2H_q2TONG-zE8-KG/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=102221470053630279435&rtpof=true&sd=true

This is for a game, but I'm interested in what I could do with the real life applications that would come from this (ie resource management).  I'm sure that there is a simple way through this but I just cant see it right now.

Can anyone offer some help?

Final table I am envisaging looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZeRy.png)

Scenario Below:

3 Stages:

**Stage 0  Flower Patch**

1. Flower patch that has a set output depending upon level (Output is flowers).
   No heros stationed here.

**Stage 1: Flower Shop: Converts Flowers to Bouquets**

2. 5 unique heros with different usage and efficiency rates.
3. Heroes convert the flowers received from Stage 1 into bouquets to be used in Stage 2

**Stage 2: Gift Shop: Converts Bouquets to Gifts**

4. 5 unique heros with different usage and efficiency rates (Also unique and not interchangeable with Stage 1)
5. Heroes convert the bouquets received from Stage 1 into gifts (Final Prize)
6. Output here will depend upon both Hero efficiency and usage in Stage 2 AND output of Stage 1 Hero.

I can't hardcode efficiency levels in as these change depending on what level the specific hero is, which is pulled through from a vlookup.

So in this case efficiency for ABC and ZYX would be the best looking at the raw tables, however, in terms of actual output, ABC/CBA combo actually returns the best overall yield for the given time while being slightly more inefficient.

Manual inputs required are in Purple here.

VBA is not appropriate here so I have to go down a formula route.

I have read info on What If Analysis Data Table options which seems to fit, but for the life of me I can't seem to extrapolate from the lessons/tutorials to a non direct version.  I am Vlookuping on multiple occasions to get the exact info etc so I'm struggling with how I can get this into a single formula for use in a What If Data Table

I've never used the What If Functions before and have struggled to find anything on t'internet with that consider the more complex situations.  Equally if someone has come across a good tutorial that isn't just calculating interest rates on loans(!!) please point me in that direction.

Comment: The link to the file is not working. Can you please publish your data in the post itself? It might become clearer what you are trying to achieve. You can use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to easily post your data as table so we can copy them down.